# Can Linux distros be installed without touching the boot volume AT ALL?

Tags: linux-mint, osx, dual-boot

Specifically, I'm trying to install Linux Mint 18.3 Cinnamon (the  suggested distro for development with the Xojo cross-platform development environment) to an *EXTERNAL* drive without touching the boot drive **at all** as I'm using a Mac and can boot the volume by just holding down the "Option" key upon booting the system.

I've tried using the option in the installer that says to put the boot loader on the external drive but it still touches the boot drive.

I already read the first two suggested answers as well.

Using a Virtual Machine isn't an option because my system only has 8gb of physical ram.

Comment: You have a couple of alternatives: 1. Make a persistent live drive using mkusb. Such a drive will work well [also] from an external SSD or hard disk drive, 2. Make an installed system in your drive using a computer, where you can unplug, disconnect or disable your internal drive, so that it cannot be seen by the installer. Then things will be installed into the external drive. Please notice that an installed system can be portable, if you avoid proprietary drivers. Once connected to the Mac, you can install proprietary drivers, if it makes things work better (usually graphics or wifi).

Comment: See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/942312#942312) for more details.